# React Native app not catching Prisma schema updates with generated GraphQL

Tags: react-native, prisma, nexus, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

I have a React Native project running with Prisma for typing and Nexus for graphql codegen.

It works fine until i try to update my Schema.prisma file and runcodegen to generate a new graphql schema.

The app just doesn't communicate with the db anymore, even though I know its still connected.  The mutations and queries that get updated are not recognized by the app, and return as undefined, so the connection just times out.  Reverting back to my old schema fixes it.

I run all the new migrations, rung prisma generate, prisma db pull, etc, its says the app is up to date with my db but I still get this problem.

I also make sure to do a fresh app build thru xcode but it doesn't help.

Any suggestions on how to handle updating my schemas?